# Cannot get device id after upgrade android os from version 9 to 10

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have problem on getting unique device id:
Settings.Secure.getString(this.contentResolver, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)

- On version below and equal version 9, I can get device id.
- Onversion 9, I cannot get device id.

Comment: See the following page, which explains which kind of identifiers should be used for which purposes in Android: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get device ID:

```
private String deviceID;
deviceID=Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                                                   Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```